# Unable to access GetElementById for datepicker and hidden fields (.Net WebBrowser Control)

Tags: .net, browser, controls, getelementbyid

I am doing a web scraping tool, which will extract data from site automatically based on given start and end date. These dates are actually a picker (But not sure about either it’s Js picker or something else). After changing these dates, I have apply change button and upon clicking this button, grid will be loaded.

![The datepicker control][1]
I am using .net windows application with C#. In the form, I have web browser control. Am retrieving site data through HtmlElement class object. With this, I can change start and end date text box programmatically using setattribute option. But when I focus after changing the date, it shows current date (no reflection in picker). Below attached my code:

```
HtmlElement startdate = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_txtStartDate_dateInput_text"); 

if (startdate != null)
{
startdate.SetAttribute("Value", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("M/dd/yyyy"));

}
![Selecting a date][2]
```

When I looked at source page, there was an hidden input tag which actually gets reflection if I change the date manually. I even changed the value of that hidden input tag. But no Luck. Below attached that hidden input tag found in source page:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="ctl00_txtStartDate_calendar_SD" id="ctl00_txtStartDate_calendar_SD" value="[[2013,3,19]]">
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00_txtStartDate_calendar_AD" id="ctl00_txtStartDate_calendar_AD" value="[[1980,1,1],[2099,12,30],[2013,3,1]]">
But actual date textbox control source tag is this:
<input type="text" value="3/12/2013" id="ctl00_txtStartDate_dateInput_text" name="ctl00_txtStartDate_dateInput_text" class="riTextBox riEnabled" style="width:65px;" maxlength="524288">
```

NOTE: Even this actual input value is not reflecting any changes if I change the date in that picker.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use your browswer's debugger to look at what is actually being sent in the HTTP request when you click the button on the form. That will give you a hint to what you are doing wrong.

See step 2,3,4 here: http://brannockdevice.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-wget-for-screen-scraping-html.html